# PHP Paypal IPN fails sometimes

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have a php script that I have been using for 2 years and modified it to work when paypal changed to http 1.1. It has worked for almost every transaction, but recently failed and I cannot figure out why. Below is the code.

It fails when trying to look at response. It is INVALID

Could it have something to do with non standard characters in the address?

I have tried sending the ipn request again and again and it always fails

```
function paypal_ipn() {
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&{$key}={$value}";
    }

    $res = '';
    $ch = curl_init(paypal_url());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));   
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(PAYPAL_IPN_DEBUG && !empty($_POST)) {
        $fname = 'ipn_intial_' . date('Y.m.d-h.i.s', time()) . '.txt';
        file_put_contents('log/' . $fname, $req);

        $fname = 'ipn_intial_result_' . date('Y.m.d-h.i.s', time()) . '.txt';
        file_put_contents('log/' . $fname, $res);

    }

    if(strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

        switch($_POST['txn_type']) 
{
        case 'web_accept':
            $data = array();
            $data['name'] = $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'];
            $data['email'] = $_POST['payer_email'];
            $data['txn_id'] = $_POST['txn_id'];
            $data['payment_status'] = 'Completed';
            $res = save_payment($data);
            if ($res) {
                $data = payment_details(array('txn_id' => $data['txn_id']));
                mail_notification($data);
            }            
            break;

        case 'subscr_signup':
            $params = array();
            $params['name'] = $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'];
            $params['email'] = $_POST['payer_email'];
            $params['subscr_id'] = $_POST['subscr_id'];
            $params['subscr_status'] = 'payment';

            $data = save_subscription($params);
            subscr_notification($data);
            break;
        case 'subscr_cancel':
            $data = subscr_details(array('subscr_id' => $_POST['subscr_id']));

            if ($data)
            {
                mysql_update('subscriptions', array('subscr_id' => $_POST['subscr_id']), array('subscr_status' => 'cancelled', 'cancel_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    if(PAYPAL_IPN_DEBUG && !empty($_POST)) {
        $fname = 'ipn_' . date('Y.m.d-h.i.s', time()) . '.txt';
        file_put_contents('log/' . $fname, serialize($_POST));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky one. Magic Quotes was turned off and this script assumes magic quotes is on. Therefore there is no need to called `stripslashes` This was causing the error